# Почему код работает в java 7 и не работает в java 8?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

Я использую в данный момент IDE Eclipse Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2) и версию java Version 8 Update 131.

В данном коде IDE выдает ошибку - "Type mismatch: cannot convert from byte to Integer":

```
Integer i = (byte) 10;
```

Но этот код вполне корректно выполняется в IDE Eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 2 и java Version 7. Что принципиально изменилось в механизме widening conversion в 8-й версии java, потому что я не думаю, что это связано с версией IDE?

Comment: этот код выдает одинаковую ошибку, если запускать его в java 7 или 8 из консоли - в спецификации java нет описания что будет применяться   двойное преобразование "на лету" - сначала byte к int, а затем int к Integer. Поэтому я делаю вывод, что эта проблема относится к компилятору Eclipse, наверное он изменился в Eclipse Neon

Comment: http://ideone.com/G2CQL6

Comment: Да, я тоже проверял - это ошибка компилятора Eclipse, если это можно считать ошибкой.

Comment: @VitalyVlasov, у Eclipse появился свой компилятор Java? Ткните, pls, в ссылочку на это выдающееся событие.

Comment: [http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/] Пожалуйста. А вот обсуждение разницы - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler]